Android math app supporting the computation of the beauty of a set of numbers based on what the digits look like across all of a set of bases
I am looking at investigating whether it possible to compute the beauty of a set of numbers based on what the digits look like across all of a set of bases?
More generally, in order to accomplish my goal, I would first be looking at obtaining data from an app which worked as follows:
I am looking for a sequence specifier
For an infinite sequence (or finite sequence with cyclic repetition).
After this, you specify a number
The application lists all representations of the number
using
the numbers of the sequence as a base (in the given, order
To make the digits unique, repeated numbers or symbols in the sequence (the digit sequence for the number systems), is listed inside a set of round brackets, whose number of parentheses on each side matches the repetition number (or, alternatively, the repetition number minus one). For example, if 1 appears in the sequence three times, it will be, as a digit, (1) ((1)) (((1))) or 1 (1) ((1)), according to writing preference.
You may also ask what if you could insert spaces in the number systems digits sequence.
....
Where can I find such an app?
Is anyone willing to implement this as an Android app?
Thank you for your support.

Perhaps the hardest part of this app is to cater for a system in which the digits of the digit sequence can be specified, which is generic enough to account for a variety of cases.

As mentioned, digits can repeat, but can be disambiguated using a system of counted parentheses around the digits.

The beauty of the numbers represented can be then computed, even after stripping the sequence of the parentheses.
